Combo box across both sides of same stud
I want to change 2 switches into 2 switches and an outlet. I want one faceplate for a clean look, however, the 2 outlets are on opposite sides of the stud. Do they make a faceplate that would span the gap of the stud? Or do I need to move the switch to same side of stud?

There are 3-gang faceplates which would probably work, though you might have to shim out one or both boxes to make it fit correctly. But it will look rather strange with the blank section in the middle.

use one of these https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Tamper-Resistant-Combination-Switch-and-Outlet-White-R62-T5225-0WS/202035011

Getting the spacing right would be hard (if not impossible), but a wireless switch in the middle (Lutron caseta/pico) might just work. Failing that, move everything left or right (which depends on having enough wire length) and patch.

Thinking more about it, you’d probably need a 4 gang with 2 wireless switches in the middle.
